# Print document and create PDF in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I've got some information I would like to output to a printer, but also as a PDF. I would be great if the PDF and the printing output would look the same. As what I understand, PDF reading and creating is not supported in C#.

I can create PDF's easily with external librarys like iTextSharp, but I don't know how to print them without using a different application, like Adobe Acrobat.

What are my options?

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using a 3rd party PDF printer driver; such as PDFCreator, or CutePDF.

CutePDF has a royalty-free developer version (for purchase) with programmatic access via the Registry.

The only other option that I've come across is using MigraDOC + PDFSharp, but you must author the document via MigraDOC / PDFSharp directly, it can't be a "pre-made" PrintDocument.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF there's PDF viewer controls.  I'm not sure if you're using WPF, but if you want to view PDF's inside your own app, this could be a solution. Have a look at [this](http://hugeonion.com/2009/04/06/displaying-a-pdf-file-within-a-wpf-application/).

Comment: This app seems to use Acrobat dll, though I get an error when I try to use it:
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID  failed due to the following error: 80040154.
Tried with some solution changing platform to X86, but without success.

Comment: seems some COM class hasn't been registered with the system it seems. Not sure how to resolve :(

Answer (score 0):

Sending a PDF directly to a printer requires a library to interpret the PDF,YOu can probably use Acrobat directly, but something like GhostScript will be more efficient.

Comment: I don't want to be forced to install other applications. External dll-files is ok though.